# In SymmetricDS, how to change the ownership of new files?

Tags: beanshell, symmetricds

I've configured SymmetricDS to upload files from `C:\files` (Windows machine) to `/home/foo/files` (CentOS server).

SymmetricDS is running as `root` user on CentOS server, so new files and changed files are created with `root:root` permissions. Is possibile to change the ownership of these files (say to `foo:users`) just after uploading them?

I know I can use http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html/configuration.html#filesync-beanshell after_copy_script script, but I can't find any example and I have no Java knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cron job calling periodically a shell script that will be changing the ownership of all files under `/home/foo/files/`. No need for Java development

Comment: Easy solution... but not the one I wanted :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Solved: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chown foo:users " + targetBaseDir + "/" + targetFileName);`